# Template to see list of all files in windows drive

Tags: zabbix

Is there any template or way available in zabbix server, with the help of which we can browser through all data/files available on Zabbix-agent(installed on windows system)?

Answer (score 0):

That is not available out of the box, but is requested in [ZBXNEXT-712](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-712). That issue also has a user parameter for performing low-level discovery of directories, which you can adapt to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but how how to configure the .pl script??

Comment: How to use that Perl script with Zabbix? Well, there are two parts: a user parameter and low-level discovery. For user parameters, see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/userparameters . For low-level discovery, see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/discovery/low_level_discovery . However, what exactly should be done and whether this script or LLD are the right tools for the job depends heavily on what you wish to accompilsh. If you could clarify that, it might help those who wish to answer.